# Automatically Fix Missing IDs

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need a prolong fix for a problem that I had for months.
The problem is, everytime I delete a row of data from my database, the IDs all get messed up. Even the Auto-Increment system get messed up. Any solution for this problem?

Here's what I mean:
[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI6HK.jpg)

Thanks,
CrAzYz_

Comment: I'm sure the ids are fine.  They are just not what you expect.  Once a primary key has been assigned to a row, there is no reason to change it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please view my link that I just added. It's quite hard to explain tbh.

Comment: Please explain why is that a problem for you. And don't post links to images. Post your sample data as text.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I just want the list to look nice; no messy IDs. And sorry, I can only do it this way as its hard to copy over.

Comment: Say if you had 1,2,3,4,5 and you delete 3, what would you expect the next row to be?

Comment: @Farkie 6. But I need it to auto-correct itself. Possible?

Comment: It already would be 6, what do you mean by auto correct itself?

Comment: @Farkie Fixing the wrong IDs. Like: 1,2,4,5,6 to 1,2,3,4,5,6. Pretty hard to explain from my side.

Comment: Then auto increment is not what you want, and also it's going to make everything a lot harder to track. What if you email out a link to one of them? as soon as someone deletes any row, your links are broken

Comment: If you've deleted 3 and insert 6, what should be inserted as 3...?

Comment: @Farkie I agree.

Comment: @JimL Alright, here's it. Is it possible to create a CRON job in PHP to constantly pushdown the INTs? Like: 1,2,4,5,6 to 1,2,3,4,5. That's probably my only thing I need.

Comment: you can, but it's stupid and it's just adding complexity to something you really don't need to add complexity too. Just live with it - it'll help you out

Comment: @Farkie Alright. But I asked because one developer that I know of before had told me a simple fix to it. All coded in PHP. Sadly, the code snippet is gone and he too. Therefore, I'm asking if anyone knows of it.

Comment: You can, but there are major drawbacks. Like a link/bookmark to article 10 suddenly showing article 11 (which is now 10). If you have 1M rows and delete id 1 you will have to update 999 999 rows. you will also have to update any relations when "adjusting" the ids (ie comments belonging to article 5 should now belong to article 4). All in all a lot of work for what seems like no benefit. End users usually only see titles and/or slugs of titles of what resource they are getting. No one really cares if the ids are in order, some databases (like nosql) don't even have incrementing ids (guid)

Comment: @JimL Alright because my website will show the IDs. Because, its needed. Sad part.

Comment: But will they care there are missing Ids? If anything I'd be confused if ids I had deleted were still present ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment (although I did try).

When a row is inserted into a database, it should have a primary key.  That way, you can uniquely identify the row (say for `update` or `delete`).  And, you can refer to it explicitly (using a `join` or foreign key reference).  That is a critical purpose of having primary keys.

In MySQL, this primary key is often assigned using `auto_increment`.  This is a sequential number that gets assigned to rows as they are inserted.

When rows are deleted, the primary keys **do not change**.  This is *very important*.  Other rows may refer to them.  Someone might have written down the id of the row and might expect it to be in the database the next time they look.

In other words, you are looking for functionality that is not appropriate.  My advice is to "get over it".  The auto incremented id is doing *exactly* what it is supposed to be doing.  There is no reason to change it so there are no gaps.

Comment: So, what you're saying is to just let it be and ignore the problem?

Comment: There is no problem, trust me you would get way more problems if you tried to "fix" this

Comment: Yes, ignore the "problem".